# A better solution to validate JSON unmarshal to nested structs

Tags: json, go, validation

There appears to be few options to validate the source JSON used when unmarshalling to a struct. By validate I mean 3 main things:

- a required field exists in the JSON
- the field is the correct type (e.g. don't force a string into an integer)
- the field contains a valid value (value range / enum)

For nested structs, I simply mean where an attribute in one struct has the type of another struct:

```golang
type Example struct {
    Attr1 int        `json:"attr1"`
    Attr2 ExampleToo `json:"attr2"`
}

type ExampleToo struct {
    Attr3 int `json:"attr3"`
}
```

And this JSON would be valid:

```json
{"attr1": 5, "attr2": {"attr3": 0}}
```

To keep this simple, I'll focus simply on integers. The concept of "zero values" is the first issue. I could create an `UnmarshalJSON` method, which is detected by JSON packages, including the standard `encoding/json` package. The problem with this approach is that is that is does not support nested structs. If `ExampleToo` has an `UnmarshalJSON` method, the `ExampleToo.UnmarshalJSON()` method is never called if unmarshalling to an `Example` object. It would be possible to write a method `Example.UnmarshalJSON()` that recursively handled validation, but that seems extremely complex, especially if `ExampleToo` is reused in many places.

So there appears to be some packages like the `go-playground/validator` where validation can be specified both as functions and tags. However, this works on the struct created, and not the JSON itself. So if a field is tagged as `validation:"required"` on an integer, and the integer value is `0`, this will return an error because `0` is both a valid value and the "zero value" for integers.

An example of the latter here: https://go.dev/play/p/zqSUksPzUiq

I could also use pointers for everything, checking for `nil` as missing values. The main problem with that is that it requires dereferencing on each use and is a pretty uncommon practice for things like integers and strings.

One thing that I have also considered is a "sister struct" that uses pointers to do validation for required fields. The process would basically be to write a validation method for each struct, then validate that sister struct. If it works, then deserialize the main struct (without pointers). I haven't started on this, just a concept I've thought about, but I'm hoping there are better validation options.

So... is there a better way to do JSON/YAML input validation on nested structs? I'm happy to mix methods where say `UnmarshalJSON` is used for doing some work like verifying fields exist, but I'd like to pass that back to the library to let it continue to call `UnmarshalJSON` on subsequent nested structs. I'd also rather defer to the JSON library for casting values into the struct, etc.

Comment: Use a JSON schema. You can use a JSON schema validator to validate JSON before unmarshaling it

Comment: +1 for @BurakSerdar solution. You might want to take a look here: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-go.